# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lotus/domino/axis/transport/http/NotesSocket.openConnection()V

Tags: java, soap, java-native-interface, lotus-domino, lotus

I want to test my domino web service consumer in intellij idea project

I have c:/Notes in my environments variables

Also I have all required domino jar files and also web service consumer %%object%%.jar and %%webserviceresource%%.jar

but still I have an exception

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lotus/domino/axis/transport/http/NotesSocket.openConnection()V

I understand that there is no some native method in my classpath. Maybe c:/Notes is not enough

Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: Can you please provide the block of code where you call that and the complete stacktrace. What do you mean by "having c:/Notes in my environment variables", what variables are that in particular. On a Windows System the value should rather be `C:\Notes` (backslash not forward slash). What is the content of C:\Notes, especially, are there the shared libraries or are they in some subdirectory (e.g. `Notes/shared/win`)

Comment: So c:/Notes it's a root directory of my lotus notes. There're many dll files there, which is required to work with native domino java methods. Domino jars I've added with gradle task and put in my classpath with gradle too. Block of code is just a simple request to webserviceproducer. And yes C:/Notes is a windows environment variable

Comment: When I send request from domino agent all is ok. I have an issue when I tried do it locally from my idea project. I think that I didn't include something to my classpath. But I don't know what exactly. Maybe someone had already solved that and can share with me solution

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkErrors occur if the java class is trying to access native code in a shared library and the shared library in question can't be loaded or found.

Comment: I added all dll from notes directory to java.library.path but it still doesn't work.

Comment: A reason why it still doesn't work might be that you're using a 64 bit JVM and the DLLs are all 32 bit (or vice versa)

Comment: If it was so I'll be have an exception that cannot load nlsxbe.dll because dll has 32 bit. I think in that case we have some restriction of domino dlls

Comment: I even found that this function in C:\Notes\nnotes.dll and include this dll to my gradle project. But I still have the same error.