# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lotus/domino/axis/transport/http/NotesSocket.openConnection()

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I have an issue with native java method.

I even load this dll file manually in static block:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("nnotes");
    }
```

But still have an exception:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   lotus/domino/axis/transport/http/NotesSocket.openConnection()

I run my code via intellij idea with appropriate jre

[Here's the result of DLL Export Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slOCR.png)

I readlly don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? What native method are you calling?

Comment: I call one of the web service consumer methods from intellij idea project. Native methods exactly the same as you can see in the exception description. And if you take a look in the dll export viewer you will see that definition in dll is right

Comment: I suspect that message is telling you that code inside of NotesSocket.openConnection is referring to an unsatisfied link - something outside of nnotes.dll that hasn't been loaded - presumably because nnotes.dll failed to find it on the path.

Comment: I think so too but I haven't found anything at the time. Anyway thank you for help Richard!

Comment: I see that you have another question about this same problem. Please don't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lotus/domino/axis/transport/http/NotesSocket.openConnection()V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449611/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-lotus-domino-axis-transport-http-notessocket-ope)

Comment: I search duplicate with dll export viewer but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the way to work with domino web service consumer from intellij idea.

But you can generate that consumer with apache axis jars manually and it works fine.